# LINQ update query is not updating database records in Xamarin forms app

Tags: linq, xamarin.forms

I am trying to update database using LINQ query, to update 'SoccerAvailability' table records where x.Email == emailTextVal. I have written my update query and its not updating in my Xamarin forms app, please advise if there is anything to fix in my query

```
var availability = context.SoccerAvailability.Where(x => x.Email == emailTextVal);

foreach (var available in availability )
{

    available.SoccerStatus += bonusToAdd;
    available.CurrentDate += scoreToAdd;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with xamarin but do you need also to tell the system to update after change the bound values in the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are just updating the object that exists in memory.  To persist this change back to your database you need to call `Update`

```
var availability = context.SoccerAvailability.Where(x => x.Email == emailTextVal);

foreach (var available in availability )
{

    available.SoccerStatus += bonusToAdd;
    available.CurrentDate += scoreToAdd;

    // assuming context is an SQLiteConnection
    context.Update(available);
}
```

Comment: Will try and let you know Jason